# Query XML parameter in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

This seemed like a great idea on Friday afternoon but I'm having a bit of trouble. I've not used SQL XML querying before so I may of just done something incredibly stupid. Basically I want to pass a series of strings to query a table into a Stored Procedure.

I thought about this for a bit, considered using a CSV and then decided to attempt to do this using XML. So My XML looks like:

```
<Root>
  <string>value</string>
  <string>value</string>
  <string>value</string>
  <string>value</string>
</Root>
```

I'm passing this into a stored proc as an XML value type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateHotelImages
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @hotelID int, 
    @imageIDs xml
AS
BEGIN
```

so I want to *shred* the XML into a table of strings.

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT Child.value('(string)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM @imageIDs.nodes('/Root/') AS N(Child))
```

But I keep getting the error message `XQuery [nodes()]: Syntax error near '<eof>', expected a "node test".`

I may well be doing something incredibly stupid here so any help will be gratefully received.

**Update**

I've broken it down into a single query to help:

```
DECLARE @imageIDs xml
SET @imageIDs = '<Root>
  <string>value</string>
  <string>value</string>
  <string>value</string>
  <string>value</string>
</Root>'

SELECT Child.value('(string)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
        FROM @imageIDs.nodes('/Root/') AS N(Child)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the last `/` in the nodes function.

```
SELECT Child.value('(string)[1]', 'varchar(200)') 
FROM @imageIDs.nodes('/Root') AS N(Child)
```

or alternatively

```
SELECT Child.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(200)') 
FROM @imageIDs.nodes('/Root/*') AS N(Child)
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That's helped, no longer getting exception but it only returns a single row?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of trailing `/` in your nodes expressions. It should just be `/Root`.

BTW, I think you are looking for a `SELECT` to return the values as a table which is achieved by the following:

```
DECLARE @imageIDs XML

SELECT @imageIDs = '
<Root>
  <string>value</string>
  <string>value2</string>
  <string>value3</string>
  <string>value4</string>
</Root>'

SELECT 
    Child.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM @imageIDs.nodes('/Root/string') AS N(Child)
```

Results:

```
value
value2
value3
value4

(4 row(s) affected)
```